# Represent an Embedded MongoDB Document when defining an Entity Class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

My goal is to initialize a class that represent a document (Book) that has a containing document (Details). Developing in ASP.NET / C# / MongoDB.

I have the following C# class:

```
Public Class Book{

  public BsonString Name {get; set;}

}
```

How do I add an embedded document to that class.

For example:

I want the `details` to be included as a sub collection (embedded document) inside the parent document when I insert it to MongoDB database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go:

```
public class Book
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Details Details {get; set;}
}

public class Details
{
    public DateTime PublishDate {get; set;}
    public string Author {get; set;}
}
```